# How can i use constants in vuejs template?

Tags: vue.js

how can i use constants in the template of the vuejs?

this is my code, I'm declaring this constants `import TIPS from '../../constants/tipsConstants'` and i want to use in the template like this `onWhiteListedMint(TIPS.TIP_A)`

```html
<template>
  <el-row class="row" justify="center">
    {{ACTION_CARD.ACTION_A}}
    <CustomCard
      @onClick="isListed(TIPS.TIP_A)"
    />
```

```js
import TIPS from '../../constants/tipsConstants'
  
  export default {
    name: 'Main',
    props: {
```

the content of tipsConstants is:

```js
export const TIPS = { TIP_A: 'TIP_A', TIP_B: 'TIP_B', TIP_C: 'TIP_C'}
```

i am getting this error

```
35:10  error    'TIPS' is defined but never used
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tipsConstants.js` has a [*named export*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#using_named_exports) for `TIPS`, so the component would have to use a *named import*:

```js
import { TIPS } from '../../constants/tipsConstants'
```

You could expose `TIPS` to the template through a data property. Since you likely don't need reactivity on it, use [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) on the imported object as shown below:

```js
import { TIPS } from '../../constants/tipsConstants'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      TIPS: Object.freeze(TIPS),
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-using-imports-in-template?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)

Comment: You technically *can* expose `TIPS` directly without `Object.freeze()`, but then the object will be made reactive (i.e., Vue will track changes to the object) unecessarily because the object is not going to change (they're all constants). A data property is reactive by default, but you have the option of making it not-reactive with `Object.freeze()`.